# Increment a counter in a constant function

Tags: c++, loops

I'm attempting to keep a counter of how many times a while loop is run through. However, the code was given to me, and I'm not sure which way to modify the code to be able to increment the code.

```
int findPos( const HashedObj & x ) const
{
    int offset = 1;
    int currentPos = myhash( x );

    while( array[ currentPos ].info != EMPTY &&
           array[ currentPos ].element != x )
    {
        currentPos += offset;  // Compute ith probe
        offset += 2;
        incrementCounter++;
        if( currentPos >= array.size( ) )
            currentPos -= array.size( );
    }

    return currentPos;
}
```

When I compile this, I get "incrementCounter cannot be modified because it is being accessed through a const object"

When I see this, I know that I can't edit a value in a const function, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Where's the definition for `incrementCounter`?

Comment: incrementCounter is declared in the public definition of the class that this method is contained in.

Comment: You *could* make `incrementCounter` be `mutable`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare `incrementCounter` as `mutable` like this:

```
mutable int  incrementCounter;
```

Then you will be able to change it in the `findPos` function.

> **[mutable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv)** -
>   applies to **non-static** class members of non-reference non-const type and specifies that the member does not affect the externally visible state of the class (as often used for mutexes, memo caches, lazy evaluation, and access instrumentation). **`mutable` members of const class instances are modifiable.**
>   (Note: the C++ language grammar treats mutable as a storage-class-specifier, but it does not affect storage class.)

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for and fixed the problem. That's what I was looking for and solved the problem I was having.